# How to select next state using Markov chain?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

the Markov chain in my case is as shown in the image attached

[image]

My query is I am not getting what will be my next state as per the given Markov chain if my current state is 2.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The image suggests that the possible states following $S_2$ will be $S_1$ with probability $0.3$ or $S_2$ with probability $0.4$ or $S_3$ with probability $0.3$

Comment: from $S_2$ there are three possible different new states: $S_1$, $S_2$ again or $S_3$, just observe the arrows going out of $S_2$

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your response. I agree that from $S_2$ there are three possible different new states: $S_1$, $S_2$ again or $S_3$. But I need to know exactly which state it can go. This is basically because I am implementing $Q$ learning along with this Markov chain and hence in the Bellman equation (which is used to update the $Q$-table in $Q$-learning) I need the to know next state if current state is $S_2$.

Comment: @Henry, Thank you so much sir for your response. My query is can we know exactly what will be the next state ?

Comment: That is the joy of probability - you do not *know* what will happen next, just what might happen and how likely it is

Comment: Ok sir, but then what value for next state should we put in the Bellman equation i.e.,  Consider the Bellman equation: $Q^{\text{new}}(s_t,a_t)  \leftarrow (1-\alpha)Q(s_t,a_t)+\alpha  r_t+\alpha \gamma \underset{a}{\text{max}}Q(s_{t+1},a)$ -----(1) where $s_t$ is current state, $s_{t+1}$ is next state.

Comment: Sir, can we do like this: If the current state ($s_t$) is 2 then 40% of the time we can keep next state ($s_{t+1}$) as 2 , 30% of the time  $s_{t+1}$ as 1 and 30% of the time $s_{t+1}$ as 3 ?